# Why is this causing a Circular Dependency in Security Group Error: CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Why is this creating a circular dependency error?

`Error: Deployment failed: Error [ValidationError]: Circular dependency between resources: [docDbSG, elasticDocDbCluster]`

I even tried separating the code for DocDbCluster and SecurityGroup in separate stacks but it still shows the same error

```js
// Fetch VPC from ID
    const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, 'docDbVpc', {
      vpcId: props!.vpcId
    });

    const securityGroup = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'docDbSG', {
      vpc: vpc,
    });

// Add ingress rules
// I believe this is where the issue is coming from, if I remove this line it works
    securityGroup.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.securityGroupId(securityGroup.securityGroupId), ec2.Port.allTraffic());

    new docdbelastic.CfnCluster(this, 'elasticDocDbCluster', {
      adminUserName: props!.AdminUserName,
      adminUserPassword: "password",
      authType: props!.AuthType,
      clusterName: props!.ClusterName,
      shardCapacity: props!.ShardCapacity,
      shardCount: props!.ShardCount,
      subnetIds: props!.dataSubnets,
      vpcSecurityGroupIds: [securityGroup.securityGroupId],
    });
```

EDIT:

How to add security group as a source itself in its rules without creating circular dependency?

Comment: does it make a difference if you use the group as peer directly? `securityGroup.addIngressRule(securityGroup, ec2.Port.allTraffic()))`
Not sure why it sees a circular dependency there, If it fails because of that it should fail without that db cluster, maybe because the actual group id cannot be resolved until the group is created

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the error is misleading.
While

```
securityGroup.addIngressRule(ec2.Peer.securityGroupId(securityGroup.securityGroupId), ec2.Port.allTraffic());
```

gives a circular dependency error between the **DocDBCluster and SecurityGroup**, commenting out the docDbCluster still generates a circular dependency error -

> Deployment failed: Error [ValidationError]: Circular dependency between resources: [docDbSG]

This means that the security group itself has a circular dependency. It is probably due to accessing the `securityGroupId` before it is being created.

A workaround provided by Zapl in the comments works -

```
securityGroup.addIngressRule(securityGroup, ec2.Port.allTraffic());
```

Another approach suggested by Andre also works -

```
securityGroup.connections.allowInternally(ec2.Port.allTraffic());
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you are causing a circular dependency. Here is how you do it:

```
securityGroup.connections.allowInternally(ec2.Port.allTraffic());
```

Comment: This does not answer why there is a circular dependency between the SG and the cluster, though

Comment: I don't see a circular dependency between the SG and the cluster. Would you mind pointing it out @gshpychka? There was a circular dependency between the SG and itself, as the OP was trying to grant internal access without using the `allowInternally` method.